# What is the behavior of the ampersand operator in R's sum(...) function

Tags: r

Below, a line from a script I'm translating from R into Python. I'm more experienced at Python than I am at R, and I'm running into a little trouble here:

```
val = sum(l & f==v)
```

Let `l` be a vector of true/false values. Let `f` be a vector of trivial values, and `v` some possible value of `f` to test against. I expect `l` and `f` to be of the same length. The `f==v` part will also yield a boolean array. Now I am left with the question what the `&`/ampersand (Logical AND, according to the [R documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Logic.html)) will do in this context. Will the `sum()` function return the sum of a boolean array that indicates where both the `l` and `f==v` boolean arrays are true? Or wil it sum all true values for both arrays and add them up?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: summing logical values, TRUE is 1, FALSE is 0 (so summing the result of condition cond1&cond2, `l & f=v` is a vector of logical values of same length as `l` and `f==v`, the sum output tells you how many TRUE there are in `l & f==v`)

Comment: So for `l = [True, True, False]` and `f == v --> [True, False, True]` for instance, would yield a result of 2 + 2 = 4?

Comment: nope you will get 1 : `l & f==v` would be `c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)` (best way to see what you get is to try it...)

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let define several vectors :

```
l <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
v <- 1:5
f <- rep(c(1, 4), c(3, 2))
```

now let see what we have when we decompose your line `sum(l & f==v)`:
In this line, `==` has precedence over `&`:

```
fev <- f==v
fev
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Then we do `l & fev`:

```
lafev <- l & fev
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

lastly, we sum:

```
sum(lafev)
[1] 1
```

The sum tells us how many simultaneous `TRUE` there are in `l` and `f==v` by converting the `logical` values to numeric: `TRUE` becomes `1` and `FALSE` becomes `0`. So, in this example, 1.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate example. It's a good and helpful clarification of your comment on my initial question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample python version:

```
l = [True, True, False]
f = [True, False, True]
v = [True, True, True]
f_eq_v = [f[i] == v[i] for i in range(len(f))] # f == v in R
val = sum([l[i] & f_eq_v[i] for i in range(len(l))]) # val = sum(l & f==v) in R
```

Comment: Is there a reason you split up the final two lines?

Comment: just for the purpose of demonstration of == and & in R and python,
for instance in python f == v can't be written as it can be in R, it means completely different thing (it's not elementwise comparison).

Comment: OP is asking for an R answer, not python

Comment: His very first statement says he is 'translating from R into Python', so i assumed his code is in R and he wants the python version  @Procrastinatus Maximus.

Comment: Um. @sandipan's answer really doesn't deserve the down votes. While the OP was asking for what the R code was doing, this answer does indeed show what the R code is doing, but with a fully Python translation.  IMO the Delete flag is unwarranted as are the down votes.

Comment: Thanks @hrbrmstr, I really don't know why I was downvoted.

Comment: when an answer begins by *here is a python version* on a question tagged R, it just doesn't answer the question, which is "what does it mean in R?". Maybe an explanation around the "raw code" would have showed the potential usefulness of the answer, which I have now a glimpse at, thanks to @hrbrmstr comment